# python xlwings module error: OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error

Tags: python, pycharm, xlwings, python-3.9

I just tried to write into the excel file from python using xlwings.  By following the simple code itself facing the error.  I have  installed the latest version of Python 3.90 and `xlwings 0.20.8`. Using pycharm-community-2020.2.3 for writing codes.

Given below are the codes and the error displayed while running this code.

**Code:**

```
import xlwings as xw


excel_file = "test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(excel_file)

wb.sheets("Sheet1").range("A2").value = "Hello"
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:/Users/Siva/.conda/Sample/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
  
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Projects\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 533, in __init__
    for wb in app.books:
  
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Projects\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 374, in books
    return Books(impl=self.impl.books)
  
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Projects\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 397, in books
    return Books(xl=self.xl.Workbooks)
  
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Projects\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 313, in xl
    self._xl = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(self._hwnd)
  
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Projects\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 222, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd
    ptr = accessible_object_from_window(child_hwnd)
  
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Projects\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 190, in accessible_object_from_window
    res = oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
  
File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 948, in GetResult

OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error
```

Comment: The file `test.xlsx` exists, and you have read/write permissions to the file and you have Excel installed?

Answer (score 0):

```
service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.kyz.games.hepyek" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Please add a few lines of explanation too :)